# Adding a protected constructor to allow subclasses provide different implementations

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have the following interface (some methods ommited for simplicity):

```
public interface Container{

    public void put(String s, Object o);
    public Object get(String s);

}
```

and its implementation:

```
public class ContainerImpl implements Container{

    private Map<Stirng, Object> m;

    public ContainerImpl(){
        m = new HashMap<>();
    }

    //This constructor is used in the case if a client is not satisfied
    //by the HashMap, e.g. in case of Enum it's better to use EnumMap
    protected ContainerImpl(Map<String, Object> m){
        this.m = m;
    }

    public void put(String s, Object o){
        m.put(s, o);
    }
    public Object get(String s){
        m.get(s);
    }
}
```

My question is about if providing such a protected constructor contraries to incapsulation. In fact we give to clients some knowledge that internally we use `Map`. If the dataStructure changed, we'll have to perform a conversion from the map passed as a parameter which may probably cause some bugs, I think.

Comment: This also makes internal map accessible from outside.

Comment: @Basilevs Indeed, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have responsibilities of creation, use and encapsulation of underlying Map in a single class.
If you want to follow [SRP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), try leaving the only public constructor which accepts Map as argument, use factories or descendants to encapsulate data:

```
/** 
 * @param m - storage model. Should not be modified after call.
 */
public ContainerImpl(Map<String, Object> m){      
  this.m = m;
}

/** A new instance with default storage model */
public static ContainerImpl createDefault() {
   // Storage reference is isolated
   return new ContainerImpl(new HashMap<>());
}
```

Alternatively, delete all constructors and provide:

```
protected abstract Map<String, Object> getStorage();
```

Comment: I though about copying, but in that case we must know the specific type of the map.

Answer (score 3):

> if providing such a protected constructor contraries to incapsulation.

You are right, it does contradicts incapsulation behavior of `ContainerImpl`.

IMHO this is a design decision; whether `class` is designed to enforce incapsulation or to expose to client's/caller's for supporting varities of constructs.

For example:

**A:** `ContainerImpl` with only `default-constructor` implies that internal storage of `Container` is completely governed by it's `concrete-implementation` and caller cannot choose different storage.

**B:**
And `ContainerImpl` with

```
protected ContainerImpl(Map<String, Object> m)
```

implies that caller can choose the nature of `Map` based storage i.e. `TreeMap`, `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` or a custom implementation.

Decision on choosing one of the above approached would be based on client's need and nature.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use something like this:

```
protected ContainerImpl(Map<String, Object> m){
    this(); //default constructor, instantiates internal map
    this.m.putAll(m); // copy all values
}
```

This way you will not affect encapsulation, but you will provide some convenience. As an alternative you could provide a factory method like this:

```
protected ContainerImpl create(Map<String, Object> m){
    ContainerImpl impl = new ContainerImpl(); //default constructor, instantiates internal map
    impl.m.putAll(m); // copy all values
    return impl;
}
```

Comment: This won't allow for parametrization of storage model though.

Comment: @Basilevs What is "parametrization of storage model"?

Comment: How can client use your class if he wants `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>())` to be underlying storage? Substitution of underlying implementation is what dependency injection is about, and it is what happens here.

Comment: @Basilevs I agree, that some flexibility is lost, but it creates some encapsulation. What would your solution look like?